# JsonOutput.toJson using a JsonBuilder object adds additional "content" element

Tags: groovy, jsonbuilder

I'm using JsonBuilder to create a new Json object. Additionally I have to do an escaping of control and special charaters.

Therefore I'm using the JsonOutput.toJson which adds an additional "content" element.

sample XML input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TestRequest>
        <Note>test note....ÄäÜü ß /  $ % §  "</Note>
        <Note2>This is another note. here comes the Zeilenumbruch...bruch&#xA;...hier geh's weiter&#xA;</Note2>
</TestRequest>
```

sample coding:

```
class Mapping_41_Test_Control_Chars {
static main(args) {
    def in_xml                                      = new XmlSlurper().parse("./test/Sample_Control_Character.xml")
    def jsonBuilder                                 = new JsonBuilder()

    jsonBuilder{
        note in_xml.Note.toString()
        note2 in_xml.Note2.toString()
    }

    println "-------- prettyPrint_JsonOutput.toJson:"
    println JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(jsonBuilder));


    def json = JsonOutput.toJson([note: 'test note....ÄäÜü ß /  $ % §  "'])

    println  "-------- json:"
    println JsonOutput.prettyPrint(json)
}
```

JsonOutput.toJson:

```
-------- prettyPrint_JsonOutput.toJson:
{
    "content": {
        "note": "test note....\u00c4\u00e4\u00dc\u00fc \u00df /  $ % \u00a7  \"",
        "note2": "This is another note. here comes the Zeilenumbruch...bruch\n...hier geh's weiter\n"
    }
}
-------- json:
{
    "note": "John Doe",
    "age": "test note....\u00c4\u00e4\u00dc\u00fc \u00df /  $ % \u00a7  \""
}
```

Do you know an option to use JsonOutput with JsonBuilder and get the required output eliminating the "content" element? I need to escape the special characters therefore I cannot use toString

Thanks & Regards
Marco

Comment: Please post your code - a part responsible for creating `JsonBuilder` and part that uses `JsonOutput`.

Comment: Marco, what is the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use `JsonOutput.toJson()` when working with `JsonBuilder` - it has a method [`JsonBuilder.toPrettyString()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.12/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html#toPrettyString()) that creates a `String` representation of your JSON object.

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

def builder = new JsonBuilder()
builder {
    name 'John Doe'
    age 99
}

println builder.toPrettyString()
```

#### Output

```
{
    "name": "John Doe",
    "age": 99
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry, maybe I was not precise enough:

I'm generating a Json from an XML input which contains the following tags:
<Note>test note....ÄäÜü ß /  $ % §  "</Note>
<Note2>This is another note. here comes the Zeilenumbruch...bruch&#xA;...hier geh's weiter&#xA;</Note2>


I would have to escape the required special charaters. This is the reason why I use JsonOutput.

Comment: @Marco Please update your question then. Paste all snippets needed to reproduce the issue: part of XML, code snippet where you convert XML to JsonBuilder and how you use JsonOutput. Otherwise we don't have sufficient information to help you finding a solution to your problem.

Comment: done. put some sample coding as well as sample XML input.

Answer (score 1):

managed to get it solved via the following:

JsonOutput.toJson(jsonSlurper.parseText(jsonBuilder.toString()))